# How can I update my method using an alternative update method in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is it possible to update from an action/method other than the update action/method? For example in my users controller I already have an update method for other parts of my users account.

I need a separate one for changing my users password. Is it possible to have something like this:

```
def another_method_to_update
  user = User.authenticate(current_user.email, params[:current_password])
  if user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    login user
    format.js   { render :js => "window.location = '#{settings_account_path}'" } 
    flash[:success] = "Password updated" 
  else
    format.js   { render :form_errors }

  end
end
```

Then have my change password form know to use that method to perform the update?

It has 3 fields: current password new password confirm new password

and I use ajax to show the form errors.

Kind regards

Comment: Sure, you can have any number of methods to update/delete/edit whatever you like. You'll need to define their routes though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; the `update` action is just a default provided to make REST-based interfaces trivially easy.  You will want to make sure you have a POST route in `config/routes.rb` that references `users#another_method_to_update` presuming you're doing all this in the UsersController (and on Rails 3) but the basic answer to your question is that model operations (including updating fields) can be done anywhere you have the model available.

There's no tying between what model methods can be called and what controller methods are being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use another route for this? Stick with the convention, use the default route. If I understood correctly, your page contains a form for password update.

We could write entire code for this in the update method, but this is cleaner and more self-explanatory:

```
def update
   change_password and return if change_password?
   # old code of your update method
   # ...
end

private

def change_password?
   !params[:current_password].nil?
end

def change_password
  user = User.authenticate(current_user.email, params[:current_password])
  respond_to do |format|
    if user.update_attributes(params[:user])
     login user
     flash[:success] = "Password updated" 
     format.js   { render :js => "window.location = '#{settings_account_path}'" } 
    else
     format.js   { render :form_errors }
    end
  end
end
```

This is a lot easier to understand for someone who will look at your code since you're still calling update method to update your model which then performs custom action.

I've also fixed your custom method code.

Answer (score 0):

in config/routes.rb:

```
puts "users/other_update_method"
```